# how to load a page with popover in ionic4

Tags: ionic4, lazy-loading

How to load (lazy load) a page and not a component from popover in ionic 4?
I try like this:

```
  async CreateContent(ev: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
      component: 'ContentPopoverPage',
      event: ev,
      translucent: true
    });
    popover.onDidDismiss().then((res: any) => {
      if (res.data !== undefined && res.data != null) {
        const gallery: IGallery = res.data.contentData;
        this.galleryList.unshift(gallery);
      }
    });

    return await popover.present();
  });
```

and the error result is:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found
>   for ContentPopoverPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Comment: Have you added in entryComponents, as it suggests?

Comment: ContentPopover is a page and has it's own modal.ts file. I alzo try to put it in entrycomponent and declaraction but didnt woek

Answer (score 0):

i had routing in content-popover.module.ts like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContentPopoverPage
  }
];
```

so i change path from '' to something in my app.routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'content-popover',
    component: ContentPopoverPage
  }
];
```

after that i imported ContentPopoverPageModule in my gallery.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ContentPopoverPageModule,
    CommonModule,
    ...
```

finlay in my gallery.ts file:

```
  import { ContentPopoverPage } from '../content-popover/content-popover.page';

  async CreateContent() {
    const popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
      component: ContentPopoverPage
  });

    popover.onDidDismiss().then((data: any) => {
    });

    await popover.present();
 }
```